# Magento 2 Shipping Address Validations doesn't work

Tags: magento2, extensions

I try to create one module for display all steps together in checkout. Its like one step checkout. But I have got a very strange issue. Shipping Address validation work perfectly while I try to select shipping method directly without filling shipping address but its not working while I try click Place Order button directly. Its give only email address validation.

Anyone have idea how can I do validation on place order button click event?